# Datatables select first row after first load and reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and I have to select the first row of table.
The problem is select the first row when the table are reload (the table show the rooms of a building, so user can change the building).
This is my code:

```
function showRoom(idBuilding){

    document.getElementById("roomTable").removeAttribute("style");
    if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#roomTable' ) ) {
        roomTable = $('#roomTable').DataTable({
            responsive:true,
            select: true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No room available!"
            },
            "ajax":{
                "url": "/buildings/"+ idBuilding + "/rooms/",
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d.idRoomType = idRoomType;
                },
                "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                    if (typeof json.success == 'undefined')
                        window.location.href = "/500";
                    else if (json.success){
                        return json.result.data;
                    }else{
                        notifyMessage(json.result, 'error');   
                        return "";
                    }                           
                },  
                "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    window.location.href = "/500";
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "capacity"},
                        {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            var string ="";
                            for (index = 0; index < data.accessories.length; ++index){
                                string = string + '<i aria-hidden="true" class="'+ data.accessories[index].icon+'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+data.accessories[index].name+'"style="margin-right:7px;" ></i>';
                            }
                            return string;
                        }
                        },
                        ],
                        "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
                            if (roomTable.rows().any()){
                                roomTable.row(':eq(0)').select();
                                selectedRoom(0);                        
                            }
                            initializeCalendar();
                        }
        });
    }   
    else {
        roomTable.ajax.url("/buildings/"+ idBuilding + "/rooms/?idRoomType=" + idRoomType).load(selectFirstRow());
    }

    roomTable.off('select')
    .on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        selectedRoom(indexes);
    } );
    roomTable.off('deselect').on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        reservationForm.room = -1;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'selectable', false);
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
    } );
}
function selectFirstRow(){
    if (roomTable.rows().any()){
        roomTable.row(':eq(0)').select();
        selectedRoom(0);                        
    }
    initializeCalendar();
}

function selectedRoom(index){
    var room = roomTable.rows( index ).data().toArray()[0];
    reservationForm.room = room.idRoom;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'minTime', room.startTime);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'maxTime', room.endTime);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'selectable', true);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
}
```

On the first load all work fine, but when

```
roomTable.ajax.url("/buildings/"+ idBuilding + "/rooms/?idRoomType=" + idRoomType).load(selectFirstRow());
```

is called it seems to select the row before reload the table, so I have no row select (keep select the row of first load but now it is not visible).
Do you have idea how can I select on the load after?

UPDATE: the temporary solution is to use `destroy: true` but I would like a better solution like this:

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#roomTable' ) ) {
        roomTable = $('#roomTable').DataTable({
            destroy: true, //it is useful because with standard code I have problem with first row selection, now it create the table each time
            responsive:true,
            select: true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No room available!"
            },
            "ajax":{
                "url": "/buildings/"+ building.idBuilding + "/rooms/",
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d.idRoomType = idRoomType;
                },
                "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                    if (typeof json.success == 'undefined')
                        window.location.href = "/500";
                    else if (json.success){
                        return json.result.data;
                    }else{
                        notifyMessage(json.result, 'error');   
                        return "";
                    }                           
                },  
                "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    window.location.href = "/500";
                }
            },
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
                if (roomTable.rows().any()){
                    roomTable.row(':eq(0)').select();
                    selectedRoom(0);                        
                }
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function() {
                initializeCalendar();
            },
            "columns": [
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "capacity"},
                        {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            var string ="";
                            for (index = 0; index < data.accessories.length; ++index){
                                string = string + '<i aria-hidden="true" class="'+ data.accessories[index].icon+'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+data.accessories[index].name+'"style="margin-right:7px;" ></i>';
                            }
                            return string;
                        }
                        },
                        ],
        });
    }   
    else {
        roomTable.ajax.url("/buildings/"+ idBuilding + "/rooms/?idRoomType=" + idRoomType).load(selectFirstRow());
    }
```

But `fnDrawCallback` is called before ajax so I don't have the value, datatables keep on loading...

Answer (score 1):

The **fnInitComplete** callback is called only when the datatable is initialized, so only once. You can use the **fnDrawCallback**, which is called every time the datatables redraws itself.
Just change *fnInitComplete* to *fnDrawCallback*. More about datatable callbacks (legacy version) [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks).

Comment: it's called before data retrieving so I  don't have data

Comment: I am pretty confident it is called after the whole table redrawed itself. But, you must add that callback to table, and not to column. Like this:

`$('#example').dataTable( {
       "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
         alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
       }
     } );`

Comment: When you call `roomTable.ajax.url("/buildings/"+ idBuilding + "/rooms/?idRoomType=" + idRoomType).load(selectFirstRow());`, it should redraw the table. 

By the way, load() function is not accepting any parameter, so you should replace `load(selectFirstRow())` to `load()`.

After setting up the new AJAX url, try not to call load(), but oTable.fnDraw(); for example.